# Computation PL/SQL Expression "Identifier must be declared"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to convert a from field in lowercase with a compuatation. When I execute the update apex tell me that the Identifier must be declared.

Here my PL/SQL

```
lower(P13_CUST_EMAIL)
```

[image: Compuatation Options]

Please help me :)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the bind variable on `lower(P13_CUST_EMAIL)`, it should be `lower(:P13_CUST_EMAIL)`.  It's telling you identifier must be declared as it doesn't know what `P13_CUST_EMAIL` is.